Adapting Compilation Chain from MPLAB X IDE to VS Code with MPLAB Plugins
My code builds fine in the MPLAB X IDE (v5.454), but for usability I want to use VS Code with the MPLAB extensions.
My requirements include the use of the xc32 compiler v2.40. The example video does not cover the use of a specific compiler.
I have that compiler installed, the path is C:/Program Files/Microchip/xc32/v2.40/bin/, but the VS Code IDE cannot find it.
I couldn't find documentation on how to add it.
I learned in this stackoverflow reply, that I need to add the info into the task.json.
I am confused on how to add the content of all the nested Makefiles into a tasks.json.
Furthermore, I realized that the nested Makefiles are ignored by VS Code and the MPLAB plugins all together.
It is too much to manually add everything
How should I proceed?
Please find below the compilation output from the MPLAB X IDE.
All compiler related output from MPLAB X IDE
make -f nbproject/Makefile-default.mk SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/<my user>/<path to my project>/firmware/MY_PROJECT.X'
make  -f nbproject/Makefile-default.mk dist/default/production/MY_PROJECT.X.production.hex
make[2]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/<my user>/<path to my project>/firmware/MY_PROJECT.X'
"C:\Program Files\Microchip\xc32\v2.40\bin\xc32-gcc.exe"    -g -x c -c -mprocessor=ATSAMRH71F20C  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -O1 -I"../src/init" -I"../src/config/default/system/dma" -I"../src/config/default" -I"../src/packs/ATSAMRH71F20C_DFP" -I"../src/packs/CMSIS/CMSIS/Core/Include" -I"../src/packs/CMSIS/" -I"../src/third_party/rtos/FreeRTOS/Source/include" -I"../src/third_party/rtos/FreeRTOS/Source/portable/GCC/SAM/CM7" -I"../src/memoryprotection" -I"../src/config/default/peripheral/abcd" -I"../src/packs/ATSAMRH71F20C_DFP/component" -I"../src/config/default/peripheral/rtc" -I"../src/tasks" -I"../src/memoryprotection" -I"../src/realtimeclock" -I"../src/eeprom" -I"../src/config/default/peripheral/mpu" -I"../src/spi" -I"../src/config/default/peripheral/xyz" -I"../src/config/default/peripheral/mnop" -I"../src/config/default/peripheral/supc" -I"../src/rice" -I"../src/config/default/peripheral/qspi" -I"../src/ccc" -I"../src/device" -I"../src/extflash" -Werror -Wall -MP -MMD -MF "build/default/production/_ext/14461671/sys_dma.o.d" -o build/default/production/_ext/14461671/sys_dma.o ../src/config/default/system/dma/sys_dma.c   -mdtcm=0x40000 -mitcm=0x20000 -DXPRJ_default=default      -mdfp="C:/Users/<my user>/.mchp_packs/Microchip/SAMRH71_DFP/2.1.105/samrh71c" -I "C:/Users/<my user>/.mchp_packs/ARM/CMSIS/5.4.0/CMSIS/Core/Include" 
... many more lines like this ...
"C:\Program Files\Microchip\xc32\v2.40\bin\xc32-gcc.exe"    -g -x c -c -mprocessor=ATSAMRH71F20C  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -O1 -I"../src/init" -I"../src/config/default/system/dma" -I"../src/config/default" -I"../src/packs/ATSAMRH71F20C_DFP" -I"../src/packs/CMSIS/CMSIS/Core/Include" -I"../src/packs/CMSIS/" -I"../src/third_party/rtos/FreeRTOS/Source/include" -I"../src/third_party/rtos/FreeRTOS/Source/portable/GCC/SAM/CM7" -I"../src/memoryprotection" -I"../src/config/default/peripheral/abcd" -I"../src/packs/ATSAMRH71F20C_DFP/component" -I"../src/config/default/peripheral/rtc" -I"../src/tasks" -I"../src/memoryprotection" -I"../src/realtimeclock" -I"../src/eeprom" -I"../src/config/default/peripheral/mpu" -I"../src/spi" -I"../src/config/default/peripheral/xyz" -I"../src/config/default/peripheral/mnop" -I"../src/config/default/peripheral/supc" -I"../src/rice" -I"../src/config/default/peripheral/qspi" -I"../src/ccc" -I"../src/device" -I"../src/extflash" -Werror -Wall -MP -MMD -MF "build/default/production/_ext/404212886/FreeRTOS_tasks.o.d" -o build/default/production/_ext/404212886/FreeRTOS_tasks.o ../src/third_party/rtos/FreeRTOS/Source/FreeRTOS_tasks.c   -mdtcm=0x40000 -mitcm=0x20000 -DXPRJ_default=default      -mdfp="C:/Users/<my user>/.mchp_packs/Microchip/SAMRH71_DFP/2.1.105/samrh71c" -I "C:/Users/<my user>/.mchp_packs/ARM/CMSIS/5.4.0/CMSIS/Core/Include" 
"C:\Program Files\Microchip\xc32\v2.40\bin\xc32-gcc.exe"    -g -x c -c -mprocessor=ATSAMRH71F20C  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -O1 -I"../src/init" -I"../src/config/default/system/dma" -I"../src/config/default" -I"../src/packs/ATSAMRH71F20C_DFP" -I"../src/packs/CMSIS/CMSIS/Core/Include" -I"../src/packs/CMSIS/" -I"../src/third_party/rtos/FreeRTOS/Source/include" -I"../src/third_party/rtos/FreeRTOS/Source/portable/GCC/SAM/CM7" -I"../src/memoryprotection" -I"../src/config/default/peripheral/abcd" -I"../src/packs/ATSAMRH71F20C_DFP/component" -I"../src/config/default/peripheral/rtc" -I"../src/tasks" -I"../src/memoryprotection" -I"../src/realtimeclock" -I"../src/eeprom" -I"../src/config/default/peripheral/mpu" -I"../src/spi" -I"../src/config/default/peripheral/xyz" -I"../src/config/default/peripheral/mnop" -I"../src/config/default/peripheral/supc" -I"../src/rice" -I"../src/config/default/peripheral/qspi" -I"../src/ccc" -I"../src/device" -I"../src/extflash" -Werror -Wall -MP -MMD -MF "build/default/production/_ext/1360937237/main.o.d" -o build/default/production/_ext/1360937237/main.o ../src/main.c   -mdtcm=0x40000 -mitcm=0x20000 -DXPRJ_default=default      -mdfp="C:/Users/<my user>/.mchp_packs/Microchip/SAMRH71_DFP/2.1.105/samrh71c" -I "C:/Users/<my user>/.mchp_packs/ARM/CMSIS/5.4.0/CMSIS/Core/Include" 
"C:\Program Files\Microchip\xc32\v2.40\bin\xc32-gcc.exe"   -mprocessor=ATSAMRH71F20C -mno-device-startup-code -o dist/default/production/MY_PROJECT.X.production.elf build/default/production/_ext/14461671/sys_dma.o <path to other objectfile/object.o> build/default/production/_ext/404212886/FreeRTOS_tasks.o build/default/production/_ext/1360937237/main.o         -mdtcm=0x40000 -mitcm=0x20000 -DXPRJ_default=default      -Wl,--defsym=__MPLAB_BUILD=1,--script="ATSAMRH71F20C.ld",--defsym=_min_heap_size=512,--defsym=_min_stack_size=10240,--gc-sections,-Map="dist/default/production/MY_PROJECT.X.production.map",--report-mem,--memorysummary,dist/default/production/memoryfile.xml,-T,C:/Users/<my user>/< path to project folder>/firmware/MY_PROJECT.X/ATSAMRH71F20C.ld -mdfp="C:/Users/<my user>/.mchp_packs/Microchip/SAMRH71_DFP/2.1.105/samrh71c"
...
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 22s)
...


It seems that the numbers in the build/default/production/_ext/<number order a>/<object file a>.o change with every build.
I am new to how to configure such a complex project compilation and do bring a limited computer science background.
